# String.split() after n characters

Tags: python

I can split a string like this:

```
string = 'ABC_elTE00001'
string = string.split('_elTE')[1]
print(string)
```

How do I automate this, so I don't have to pass `'_elTE'` to the function? Something like this:

```
string = 'ABC_elTE00001'
string = string.split('_' + 4 characters)[1]
print(string)
```

Comment: [`re.search(r'\d+$', string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)…?

Comment: Regex? Split on just the underscore then slice all but the first four characters?

Comment: Do you only want `00001`?

Comment: if need to capture anything after 4 symbols, then it's re.search(r'_.{4}(.+)$', string)

Comment: Thank you for the replies. What exactly is `re.search()`? It does not seem to work. Is `re` a module?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov You can also use `re.split`, see my answer for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split()` on `_` and take everything after the first four characters.

```
s = 'ABC_elTE00001'

# s.split('_')[1] gives elTE00001    
# To get the string after 4 chars, we'd slice it [4:]

print(s.split('_')[1][4:])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
00001
```

Comment: This seems to be a very straightforward solution. are there any downsides to regex?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov not really, since you'were playing with `split()` I intended to provide a solution with it.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov this is a simpler and (tough that hardly matters) faster solution

Comment: Might I also ask how you would make it work in this code snippet: `trclist.sort(key=lambda fname: int(fname.split('.')[0].split('_elTE')[1]))`. When I add it in it does not seem to work: `trclist.sort(key=lambda fname: int(fname.split('.')[0].split('_elTE')[1][4:]))`. `trclist` is a the list containing these strings.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov What does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov I think you should accept one tho, either mine or DirtyBit's solution, your choice.

Comment: You're right, this is another topic. I will create a new post. Thank your very much

Answer (score 4):

Use regex, regex has a `re.split` thing which is the same as `str.split` just you can split by a regex pattern, it's worth a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'ABC_elTE00001'
>>> re.split('_\w{4}', string)
['ABC', '00001']
>>>
```

The above example is using a regex pattern as you see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression to automate the extraction that you want.

```
import re

string = 'ABC_elTE00001'
data = re.findall('.([0-9]*$)',string)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a, quite horrible, version that exactly "translates" `string.split('_' + 4 characters)[1]`:

```
s = 'ABC_elTE00001'
s.split(s[s.find("_"):(s.find("_")+1)+4])[1]

>>> '00001'
```